# Convert List into Numpy 2D Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How to convert a list into a numpy 2D ndarray. For example:

```
lst = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
```

Expected result:

```
>> print(arr)
>> array([[20],
       [30],
       [40],
       [50],
       [60]])

>> print(arr.shape)
>> (5, 1)
```

Comment: ``[[i] for i in x]`` or ``np.reshape([20, 30, 40, 50, 60], (-1,1))`` ?

Comment: @Yoshi thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't quite seem to help me :(

Comment: I just missreaded the question. @Sushanth answer is what I think you are looking for :)

Answer (score 4):

Convert it to array and reshape:

```
x = np.array(x).reshape(-1,1)
```

reshape adds the column structure. The -1 in `reshape` takes care of the correct number of rows it requires to reshape.

output:

```
[[20]
 [30]
 [40]
 [50]
 [60]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need your calculations more effective, use numpy arrays instead of list comprehensions. This is an alternative way using [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
x = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
x = np.array(x) #convert your list to numpy array
result = x[:, None] #use numpy broadcasting
```

if you still need a list type at the end, you can convert your result efficiently using `result.tolist()`

Comment: That's not broadcasting. It's just indexing. `None` is an alias for `np.newaxis`

Answer (score 0):

You may use a list comprehension and then convert it to numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

x = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60]

x_nested = [[item] for item in x]

x_numpy = np.array(x_nested)
```

Comment: This is a much less efficient technique. When dealing with numerical data, get it into numpy as fast as possible, then manipulate it.